# How to do lazy loading with ad hoc sql queries : SQL Filtering

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Just would like to know if its possible to do lazy loading without linq or an ORM. There are some queries I need to do that is inappropriate for ORMs. I will also need to pass the query between methods. Also, I could't find any micro orms to achieve this. Is there any way to do this?

```
var q = "Select Name from Test1"
```

Now we must add an OR or AND or IN or something else

This query will be passed to different methods to be filtered. Is there a way to do this using a micro ORM or AD Hoc SQL Queries?

Comment: Are you passing the sql query or the command class between methods?  It would help if you can give more information as to what you are trying to do.  You execute a query, but may want to wait to process the results?

Comment: The things Linq does can be coded manually (e.g., [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx)).  What is wrong with how Linq works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to express the query as some sort of in-memory object that you can further add expressions to it. For example, using some made up object hierarchy:

```
var q = Table("Test1").Select("Name");
```

You would further refine this by adding filters:

```
q = q.Where("ID= 1");
```

But of course this means that you are re-inventing [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx). You would better just embrace LINQ then and choose a provider (LINQ2SQL or LINQ2EF etc).

Another approach is to keep the string ad-hoc representation:

```
var q = "Select Name from Test1";
```

but then how do you add a filter? You have to parse the string and insert the WHERE clause. This is far from trivial. You would soon be implementing a fully fledged SQL parser ([lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29)+[yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) or [bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)+[flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser)) and a abstract syntax tree, and then serialize this as a new SQL string. Once you start thinking about joins (fairly trivial to support), subqueries (nasty), recursive table expressions (ouch) things get progresively more complex. Just browse this very site and look at how complex SQL queries can get, and imagine implementig a parse for *that*.

Many of projects I've seen tried to represent queries as some intermediate form, eg. a structure (list of fields, table name, list of WHERE conditions, list of ORDER BY clauses etc) and then add new entries in these list representation (Add a new entry in the WHERE list to add a new filter). But, in retrospect, these representations pale in comparison to what LINQ offers. I admit, LINQ is an all-or-nothing offering and you either [commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicken_and_the_Pig) yourself or not. But attempting to re-invent it only reveals the complexity of the problem. Today I would approach the problem from the other end: start with LINQ and try to keep it at bay, do not allow it to grow into a hideous monster of uncontrollable query generation tool in which every layer of the project adds some filter to the `IQueryable` and then bomb the server with something that no optimizer could even untangle.

PS. [Why I Wrote AREL](http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/) is a good read  on this whole problem.

Comment: Thanks I will use Linq. I have tried James Black solution but my project got complicated real quick. Linq is the best choice

Answer (score 7):

You could use a datareader directly, or do it through a class that would evaluate it lazily. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.100).aspx

So as a rough example, you might do something like this

```
public class LazyReader {
    SqlDataReader m_reader;
    SqlCommand m_command;
    SqlConnection m_connection;
    public LazyReader(SqlConnection connection, String sql)
    {
        m_command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        m_connection = connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Object[]> read()
    {
        using (m_connection) {
            m_connection.Open();
            m_reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (m_reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (m_reader.Read())
                {
                    Object[] values = new Object[m_reader.FieldCount];
                    m_reader.GetValues(values);
                    yield return values;
                }
                m_reader.NextResult();
            }
            m_reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to do some fiddling with the example, but the idea is to use a DataReader and read the rows one by one passing the result with a yield return through an IEnumerable which will result in lazy evaluation. Then you can pass the IEnumerable around and read as you please. Just be careful to make sure that you read consistently, otherwise the SQLConnection will terminate after 30 seconds without any activity.

Comment: I hate defending my own post. But to respond to your comment about credible and official sources, from the MSDN documentation itself "The DataReader provides an unbuffered stream of data that allows procedural logic to efficiently process results from a data source sequentially. The DataReader is a good choice when retrieving large amounts of data because the data is not cached in memory." Any ORM you find is likely going to use the DataReader directly since it is Microsoft's official API for connecting to SQL Server. My example only shows you how you might wrap it for convenience.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use `Func` or `Action` and have it define your query, so when you pass it to the next function then it can be executed when needed.

It would function as though lazy loading.

Comment: see my answer for how you could do this using the `Lazy<T>` class

Comment: @JoshE - The problem is that I have asked for clarification on what the OP is trying to do, and without it it is hard to come up with a good example of how it can be done with Lazy, Func or Action.

Comment: for sure! I just wanted to demonstrate that they are functional equivalents. It would be nice if the OP would provide more info - "...inappropriate for ORM's" is vague, as is the need to "pass query between methods". I wonder if the answer could be as simple as "hey use `IQueryable`" :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

> Lazy < T >

for this. It relies upon a Func as James suggests, but also supports caching and thread safety.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898407.aspx

EDIT: Since you are now looking for additional features of ORMs such as filtering and sorting, but with the flexibility to write raw sql, I would recommend that you look into an ORM such as Entity Framework or Nhibernate and use some of their raw sql features where appropriate like

session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);

ORMs also allow you stronger typing to eliminate mistakes when adding where filters dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The `Lazy<T>` class sounds like what you're looking for. As Kaido and James suggest, you'll need to define a method that will perform the actual loading, then pass it to the ctor of your lazy-loaded (really, initialized) object.

EX:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     Lazy<List<string>> myLazy = new Lazy<List<string>>(LoadData);
     private List<string> LoadData()
     {
        //open connection, execute your query, read/project data into a List, etc

        return new List<string> { "Hello", "My", "Name", "Is", "Earl" };
     }
}
```

The `Lazy<T>` class behaves exactly as you might expect - it defers initialization of a contained object until it is referenced via the `Value` property. See [the MDSN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [Repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) in your design.  The repository decides how to provide things to the client class.  How it is done does not matter to the consumer and it can be passed around or injected where needed.

Also consider an object cache such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).  These are especially useful if you need to "lazy load" objects non-sequentially.  Complex SQL queries can be made to return just primary keys instead of dozens of large data fields.  Store all the keys for your query and then create business objects on demand.

If you ever outgrow your implementation, Repository makes it easy to improve without affecting the classes using it.